# How to deconstruct a tuple back to its original variables

Tags: c#

I am calling a method that return a tuple as a workaround for C#  async methods not supporting  byval async parameters

```
  private  async Task< Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>> MyFunction(List<int> inputList){

      var stringList= new List<string> ();
      var intList= new List<int> ();
      ...
      return Tuple.Create(stringList, intList);
 }
```

To create a tuple from two items I use the `Create` method. However there isn't a method to return it back from where I'm calling the method.

```
 private  async Task< Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>> CallTupleFunction(){

      var intList = new List<int> ();
      var myTuple = MyFunction(intList);
      var stringList= myTuple[0]; //does not work
      intList = myTuple[1]; //does not work

 }
```

Comment: Try `myTuple.Item1` and `myTuple.Item2` instead...  [`Tuple`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx) does not expose its items through an indexer.

Comment: Try typing `myTuple.` (note the dot at the end) and see what intellisense suggests. Try google.

Comment: If I use .Item1 or .Item2 I get `Error CS1061 'Task<Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>>' does not contain a definition for 'Item1' and no extension method 'Item1' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>>' could be found`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tuple` is not a single class, it is a group of generic classes with identical name. Each class has a list of types associated with its item types, called `ItemN`. In your case you need

```
var myTuple = await MyFunction(intList).ConfigureAwait(false);
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Remove ConfigureAwait in the front end code (winforms, wpf, etc.)
var stringList= myTuple.Item1;
var intList = nmyTuple.Item2;
```

To address the `[]` syntax, it is not possible to provide an API that accesses tuple's items with an indexer, because the only possible return type for an indexer would be `System.Object`. This would be bad for two reasons:

- **Retrieving tuple's elements would require a cast** - you would have to write `var stringList= (List<string>)myTuple[0]`, which defeats the purpose of having a tuple in the first place.
- **Retrieving value-type elements would require boxing** - this would be a major concern for processing large volumes of data stored as `Tuple<,...,>`

Comment: Neither Item1 or Item2 is reconginized. If I use myTyple.Item2  I get `Error CS1061 'Task<Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>>' does not contain a definition for 'Item1' and no extension method 'Item1' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Tuple<List<string>, List<int>>>' could be found`

Comment: @choba78 That's because you are missing an `await`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight As per your example `var stringList= myTuple.Item1;` works just fine.Why would retrieving tuple's elements require cast?

Comment: @uteist I was referring to OP's suggested syntax `myTuple[0]`, and pointed out why that would not work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Tuple doesn't implement an indexer but has 2 properties of `Item1`
   and `Item2`
2. Your method is using asynchronous so first `await` it and then use the result

So:

```
var intList = new List<int>();
var myTuple = await MyFunction(intList);
var stringList = myTuple.Item1;
intList = nmyTuple.Item2;
```